# What does "expected struct `ParseError`, found fn item" mean?

Tags: parsing, rust

I am working on a parser and I keep getting an error on this part of my code.

```
impl FromStr for Binop {
    type Err = ParseError;
    
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(match s {
            "+"     => Binop::Add,
            "*"     => Binop::Mul,
            "-"     => Binop::Sub,
            "/"     => Binop::Div,
            "<"     => Binop::Lt,
            "=="    => Binop::Eq,
            _   => {return Err(ParseError); } // <---- Error Here
        })
    }
}
```

I've tried writing an actual string inside the parenthesis and a bunch of other stuff & I just can't seem to understand what the error means.

Full error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> grumpy/src/isa.rs:212:32
    |
212 |             _   => {return Err(ParseError); }
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ParseError`, found fn item
    |
   ::: grumpy/src/lib.rs:17:1
    |
17  | pub struct ParseError(String);
    | ------------------------------ fn(String) -> ParseError {ParseError} defined here
    |
    = note: expected struct `ParseError`
              found fn item `fn(String) -> ParseError {ParseError}`
help: use parentheses to instantiate this tuple struct
    |
212 |             _   => {return Err(ParseError(_)); }
    |                                          +++
```

And I defined the ParseError as `pub struct ParseError(String);`

Comment: You defined `ParseError` as a tuple struct with a `String` datum, but you don't provide that `String` when you return the error.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo So how would I fix that? I've tried `Err(String)` and `Err(ParseError(String))`, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @trab If you tried `Err(ParseError("foo"))` then that wouldn't work because `"foo"` is a `&'static str`. Try `Err(ParseError("foo".to_string()))`.

Comment: No problem. I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The named tuple requires a `String` value to be constructed. Note that a string literal has type `&str`; you need to invoke the `to_string()` method to turn it into a string:

```
Err(ParseError("foo".to_string()))
```

The compile error refers to `fn item` because by itself, in this context, `ParseError` refers to the implicit constructor function, which takes a `String` and returns a `ParseError`.